# Problema al imprimir un objeto dentro de un vector con un color asignado

Tags: java, objeto

Estoy haciendo un juego de ajedrez que se muestra por la consola de intelij mediante objetos, tengo las siguientes variables dentro del objeto

```
    //<editor-fold desc="propiedades">
    String nombre;

    String tipo_pieza;

    char dibujo;

    int pos_y;

    int pos_x;

    boolean estado;

    String color;
```

Al intentar imprimir el tablero del juego con todas las piezas en su sitio con sus respectivos colores con la siguiente función, se imprimen todas las piezas de un solo color

```
    public void imprimeTablero(char[][]tabla){
        boolean seImprime=false;

        for (int i = 0; i < maxtablero_x; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < maxtablero_y; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < listapiezas.size(); k++) {
                    if (tabla[listapiezas.get(k).getPos_x()][listapiezas.get(k).getPos_y()]==tabla[i][j] && listapiezas.get(k).getColor().equals("Azul") ){
                        System.out.print(c.blau + tabla[i][j] + c.nc + " ");
                        seImprime = false;
                        break;
                    } else if (tabla[listapiezas.get(k).getPos_x()][listapiezas.get(k).getPos_y()]==tabla[i][j] && listapiezas.get(k).getColor().equals("Rojo")) {
                        System.out.print(c.roig + tabla[i][j] + c.nc + " ");
                        seImprime = false;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        seImprime=true;
                    }
                }
                if (seImprime){
                    System.out.print(tabla[i][j]+" ");
                    seImprime=false;
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }`
```

alguien tiene alguna sugerencia de lo que podría hacer para arreglar esto?, gracias

[image: Imagen de lo que se muestra por pantalla]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal vez esté equivocado, me cuesta un poco entender que hacen tus "if", pero creo que con el siguiente cambio, podría funcionar, en todo caso, si no funciona lo comentas y seguimos buscando.

```
public void imprimeTablero( char tabla[][] ) {
    boolean seImprime = false;
    for( int i = 0; i < maxtablero_x; i++ ) {
       for( int j = 0; j < maxtablero_y; j++ ) {
          for( int k = 0; k < listapiezas.size(); k++ ) {
             Pieza pieza = listapiezas.get( k );
             if( pieza.getPos_x() == i && pieza.getPos_y() == j ) {
                if( pieza.getColor().equals( "Azul" ) ) {
                   System.out.print( "c.blau" + tabla[ i ][ j ] + "c.nc" + " " );
                   seImprime = false;
                   //break;
                }
                else if( pieza.getColor().equals( "Rojo" ) ) {
                   System.out.print( "c.roig" + tabla[ i ][ j ] + "c.nc" + " " );
                   seImprime = false;
                   //break;
                }
                else {
                   seImprime = true;
                }
             }
          }
          if( seImprime ) {
             System.out.print( tabla[ i ][ j ] + " " );
             seImprime = false;
          }
       }
       System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias funcionó bien :D, al final los break que has comentado eran necesarios pero fuera de eso, me ha funcionado, de verdad gracias, llevaba varios dias intentando solucionar este error.

Comment: Maestro, un placer ayudarte!.